# get error code in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express.js 4.2.0 and I am building my own middleware to handle errors.

In order to test it and create a `swith` statement I would like to get the code of each error such as `500`, `503` or `404`.
I have

```
exports.error = function(err, req, res, next){

    console.log("err "+err);
}
```

and I get only

`ReferenceError: db is not defined`.

Is there any way to get the code, so I can use it in a `swith` with the following logic `case 404 - send "error404", case 500 - send "error500"`

Comment: it's very likely that the status code hasn't even been set yet at that point. Don't forget to also log the stack trace. `console.log(err.stack)` the stack trace is often more useful than the error message.

Comment: Where would the code be coming from?

Comment: Shouldn't your error handler be setting the 404 and 500 status codes? If your error handler middleware is added after all routing, and is reached, the request is in some form of an error, you then need to look at the error object to figure out what kind of error it was so you can set the appropriate status code.

Comment: @KevinB. Got it. So, at what point the status code is set so I can use it?

Comment: well... that's the job of your error handler! if your error handler doesn't catch it and handle it, the last step is the built-in express one that will send 404 if no error was given, or 500 if there was an error object. you can't catch it after that.

Comment: @KevinB So, I can only get an error description and then set the status code for the client, right? Theres no other way I can access something more useful, like a code instead of a description ? Is it a smart move to use a description to a `switch`?

Comment: I wouldn't use a switch at all in this case. you don't know what is contained in `err`. It could be an instance of `Error`, a string, an object, or anything else, even undefined or null.

Comment: @KevinB You are right. Even the default error handler middleware of express sets the status according to its position. Second to last middleware > safe to guess no page found > 404. Last middleware> you leave me no choise > 500. So I guess I can set codes like express does and then build my own `switch`. Thank you